# Pay using Paypal balance when using Braintree Dropin UI

Tags: paypal, braintree

We use the Braintree Dropin UI with paypal enabled.

It works fine except for one thing: if the user has a balance at paypal, it does not give them the option to pay with their Paypal balance. They can pay with any payment method they have registered with paypal (CC, bank account), but not with their balance.

Is there a special option in the dropin UI for this? Something we need to setup in the BT control panel?

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://help.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

If you're using our [PayPal Vault flow](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/paypal/vault), buyers won't be able to choose balance as a funding source, however, PayPal will always use the balance first with all future transactions. Braintree PayPal Vault flow uses PayPal's Billing Agreements feature and PayPal requires customers to have a funding source other than PayPal balance during the Billing Agreement sign up process to ensure costs can always be covered.

With that said, once a customer goes through the PayPal Vault flow, PayPal will always use the balance first to complete payments in future, so when using the Vaulted payment method, PayPal checks if the user has any funds in the balance and other funding sources such as credit cards are only used if the user's balance can't cover the payment. They should be able to use their balance if they have sufficient funds on subsequent charges.

Comment: Thank you! This really helped. I tested an order and it worked as you described. I'd like to mark the question as 'answered' but I don't have high enough reputation to click the up-arrow on it. Since you're a BT employee, it might be good to mention to your colleagues that this should go in the docs for the paypal integration, or make it more prominent if it's already there.

Comment: Happy to hear this solved your issue. I will certainly pass your feedback along to our documentation team.